# QGraphicsScene: OpenGL with fallback

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am writing an application that must display images, and potentially loads of them. So I was wondering if there is a proper way of having a `QGraphicsScene` use OpenGL, and in case it fails, use a software renderer.

I've read the documentation, but what if setting the viewport fails?

Comment: Just because you display lots of images doesn't mean that OpenGL will speed things up. If you, for example, load the images in the GUI thread, OpenGL won't help you. How do you display the images, how many, what is the original and displayed size, how are they arranged (say table vs. mosaic), and why do you thinkg OpenGL will help?

Comment: The number of images can be up to 100-300 (indicative) at 1000x2000px, and I simply add pixmaps to the scene right now. They are arranged vertically, always (I don't know if this helps). I hope OpenGL could speed up the scrolling, although I have to implement this, that's why I'm asking before making a mistake in the project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about more than a gigabyte of textures. OpenGL by itself is of no help here, neither is a raw `QGraphicsScene`. You'll need to dynamically cache the images, ideally with prediction based on scrolling direction and speed. You'll need a coupling layer between each view and the scene, to keep the scene populated with images that are visible or will be soon visible in each view. Once you do that, OpenGL may help but you absolutely need to profile things and prove to yourself that it helps. Even without OpenGL you can have very decent performance.

Comment: Actually, OpenGL can be helpful here. If you use sparse textures, you can defer the process of loading the texture data until it becomes visible. It adds a little bit of latency, but the up-side is you don't spend 2 minutes pre-loading massive array of image data you don't immediately need.

Comment: That's precisely what I suggested to be done, without using OpenGL :)

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. But a new OpenGL feature actually means that OpenGL by itself can be of help. Using sparse [array] textures to implement this would be a ***lot*** of effort and would require a very new GL implementation, but GL is not completely out of the loop.